# Directory traversal php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a website and a person is trying to traverse the directories. All the website is secure and he cannot exploit any hole. However, as he is trying to traverse the directories, he sends 200 requests per seconds. This causes to shut down our server or slow downs to death. How can I block or protect against it?

I am using Php, Apache and MySql. I also use .htaccess file.

### Update

I have a shared hosting so I do not have access to apache to install any plugin/mode. Other similar questions on SO are for the developers with access of apache server.

Comment: This has to be resolved via one of the Apache's specific modules (best solution). If you do not have any of such modules installed .. and have no rights to install such module .. then you will not be able to do much -- better speak to your hosting company. Thing is -- any solution coded in PHP (higher level) means that request is going trough .. which means that  it's already tens times slower than lower level (via module) as PHP process must be initialized, PHP code is much slower that native C-compiled code etc